# SQL - Select ids that appear at least once in other table

Tags: sql, grails, hql, grails-orm

I'm trying to get a list of Users that appear at least once in OtherTable. The following is my very inefficient HQL query using Grails. In general, there will only be at most a few hundred users that will be run in the query but potentially a million references to those users in OtherTable.

```
List<User> users = User.executeQuery("select user " +
                    "from User as user where user.id = any(" +
                    "select otherTable.user.id from OtherTable as otherTable)")
```

How can I make this query more efficient?

Comment: If this query works, then it is probably pretty efficient.

Comment: Perhaps it was my testing hardware then? It took over a second to run on H2 with 50,000 rows of OtherTable on my PC, but the final hardware will be MS SQL on better hardware.

Comment: You can use an index in SQL Server to speed the query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, you might not have noticed, but there is a full table scan on `OtherTable`.

Answer (score 2):

This SQL might be more effcient,

```
select distinct u.id from user as u
inner join other_table ot
on u.id = ot.id
```

Here is an HQL,

```
select distinct user
from User as user
inner join user.otherTable as ot
```

Using Criteria API

```
User.createCriteria().listDistinct {
    createAlias("otherTable","ot")
    eq('id','ot.id')
}
```

Both the above would require proper mapping of your domain classes. In case, you don't have that, `OtherTable`, mapped in `User`. Try this,

```
select distinct user from User user, OtherTable ot
where user.id = ot.user_id
```

You may have noticed that we're avoiding full table scans here, completely; and it's a single query -- unlike the one you posted, which uses a subquery. Joining both entities/tables with `id` should be more efficient -- assuming `id` columns are indexed.

Comment: It is the better aproach, the in statement that others have given is nonefficient

Comment: I only need to return distinct users - the query suggested returns all of OtherTable that matches. This query is much slower with and without the distinct keyword, unfortunately.

Comment: @Anonymous1, yes, it may have contained duplicates; I modified accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```
List<User> users = User.executeQuery("select user " +
                    "from User as user where"  +
                    "user.id in (select distinct otherTable.user.id from OtherTable as otherTable)")
```

Hope it will help!